# Error downloading custom font in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, font-face

If I load my website for the first time, these errors pop-ups for every font version I have installed:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at
> https://karmel.stefvanoevelen.com//wp-content/themes/blankslate/fonts/din_alternate_bold-webfont.woff2.
> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
>
> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Din-bold"
> style:normal weight:700 stretch:100 src index:1): bad URI or
> cross-site access not allowed source:
> https://karmel.stefvanoevelen.com//wp-content/themes/blankslate/fonts/din_alternate_bold-webfont.woff2

After the second reload, it works normally. Any idea how to fix this on the first visit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix an issue for your WordPress blog, just put below into your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

As you see Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" allows you to access all resources and webfonts from all domains.